# How to remove the category with search bar in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, design

[image]

How to **remove the categories drop down** with title "All categories" attached with the search bar seen in the image attached herewith in Magento 2 ?

We just need to show the search bar only and no category list along with.

```
                  <?php if($catalogsearch) : ?>
                  <div class="catalogsearch-box">
                    <span id="select-box-category"><?php echo __('All Categories') ?></span>
                    <div id="categories-box" style="display:none;">
                      <input style="display:none;" type="text" value="" id="qsearch">
                      <ul class="cat-list dd-container" id="cat">
                        <?php
                        if($depth) $depth ++;
                          $categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magiccart\Alothemes\Model\System\Config\CatalogSearch');
                            $categories = $categoryFactory->toOptionArray($depth);
                            echo '<li data-q="0">' . __('All Categories') . '</li>';
                            foreach ($categories as $category){
                              echo '<li data-q="'.$category['value'].'" class="' . $category['class'] . '">' . $category['label'] . '</li>';
                            }
                        ?>
                      </ul>
                    </div>                        
                  </div>
```

From this code, where can I set the ***catelogsearch*** as *false* ?

Comment: I think you are using theme. So you need to find the search section.

Comment: Your top search is modified by theme. you can find in default_head_block.xml.
you will found the top search file.

Comment: I have searched for this option in the admin panel everywhere. But could not find this. Let me check the default_head_block.xml file

Comment: is there any code before `$catalogsearch`?

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

Comment: $config = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('alothemes/categorysearch', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

Comment: $catalogsearch = isset($config['enabled']) ? $config['enabled'] : 0;

Answer (score 1):

Add this code into XML where you want to remove the header:

For example remove from all the page then add to **default.xml**

**app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Follow the below steps for the solution:

1. **Login** to Admin panel
2. Go to **Catalog > Categories**
3. Select any **category** that you want
4. Under Design, select the required **Layout**.
5. Save **configuration**.